# Cambiar variable dependiendo de la value de un array en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array, function

Estoy intentando cambiar el valor de una variable después de hacer un loop a una array y verificar que los dos valores de un objeto dentro de esa array son iguales:

```
function getResult(){
   var array = this.getArray();
   var boolean = false;

   _.each(array, function(arrayValueObject){
      boolean = arrayValueObject.value1 === arrayValueObject.value2
   }

   return boolean; 
}
```

Quiero que el boolean cambie cada vez que el value1 o el value2 sean iguales o no y me lo devuelva al llamar a getResult, pero ahora mismo siempre me devuelve el valor de la comparación de los dos values del último objeto de la array -.-!

¿Cuál sería la forma eficiente y correcta de hacerlo? no se me ocurre otra forma de hacer un loop de la array (ahora lo hago con el each de underscore pero sería lo mismo que un forEach de js) para poder comparar los values del objeto que hay dentro de la misma y después asignarlo.

Gracias!!

Comment: No me queda muy claro que tipo de resultado quieres: ¿un array de booleanos? ¿`true` si se cumple para todos los elementos?

Comment: lo que quiero es que la función principal me devuelva el resultado de la comparación pero no en forma de array al final, sino el resultado de la comparación uno por uno. `false` luego `false` luego `true`...

Comment: Una función devuelve un valor. Puede ser un boolean, un array u otra cosa, pero no existe el concepto devolver *poco a poco* valores

Comment: Gracias Pablo, ya imaginaba algo así y me estaba volviendo loca, pero quería saber si había alguna posibilidad que se me escapase

Answer (score 1):

Podrías mapear tu `array` de elementos con el resultado de la comparación de ambos.

```js
function getResult () {
  const data = [{
    value1: 1,
    value2: 2
  }, {
    value1: 3,
    value2: 3
  }];
  
  return data.map(function (elemento) {
    return elemento.value1 === elemento.value2;
  })
}

console.log(getResult());
// [false, true]
```

Comment: Pues justo es a lo que llegaba siempre, pero me gustaría que me devolviese lo mismo pero uno por uno, no como un array, es decir, que me devolviese primero false y luego true, no [false, true]. Igual mil gracias!!

Comment: Tendrías que hacer llamadas diferente a una función para lograr ese resultado. Lo que puedes hacer si quieres conseguir algo en variables diferentes es destructing algo asi `const [valor1, valor2] =  getResult()` así la primera variable quedaría con el valor del primer valor del array y así sucesivamente. Pero creo que no te serviría ya que tendrías que saber la cantidad de elementos del array.

Comment: Gracias Anibal, creo que con la deconstrucción lograría algo pero no exactamente lo que quiero, tienes razón. Mil gracias por la aclaración